# macro to spilt cell from first occurence of number

Tags: excel

i hve the data like this in a single cell

```
Adadre Roos. 669.138 J2
 Aluminium Development Associat. 621.357.7:669.71 J3
 A.L.A. 669.711n j4
```

i want the text part would be 1 column and numeric part in another

so there is any macro which will find first occurence of number and split it from there to another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I got the below code from Web .altered as per your needs hope that helps*. **Tested**

```
Sub SplitText()


 Dim r As Range, rC As Range
    Dim Match, Matches
    Dim matchCount As Integer

    Set r = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown))
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Pattern = "(\d+|\D+)"
        .Global = True
        For Each rC In r
            Set Matches = .Execute(rC.Value)
            matchCount = 0
            For Each Match In Matches
                matchCount = matchCount + 1
                rC.Offset(, matchCount).Value = Match
            Next
        Next rC
    End With

end sub
```

Once you run the code then result will be like below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just use this array formula to get the text part:

```
=LEFT(A1;MIN(IFERROR(FIND({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9};A1);""))-1)
```

Values in A1 and Down, write this first formula in B1

You need Ctrl Shift Enter to enter the formula.

And then in C1 write (to get the numeric part):

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1;B1;"")
```

Depending on your regional setting you may need to replace field separator ";" by ","